# AS3 Parsing XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

Hello I keep running into errors and outputs that say "undefined" in my output panel when I try and parse XML using AS3.  I would like to get the values of score1, score2....
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Scientific

```
    ////AS3//////////

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;

    var myXML:XML;
    var xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("scores.xml"));

    function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
         myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
         trace(myXML.scores1); 

    }
    //////xml file////////////
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <root>
    <scores>
      <id>1</id>
       <score1>105</score1>
       <score2>60</score2>
       <score3>56</score3>
       <score4>48</score4>
       <score5>30</score5>
    </scores>
    </root>
    </feed>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the [descendant accessor ..](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#descendant_accessor) useful.  Example:

```
myXML..score1[0].toString()
```

**Edit:**

There is something about using the generic namespace that is causing some problems.  Adding an alias fixes it, eg:

```
<feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Otherwise Flash is expecting that you are going to use fully qualified names to specify the element you are trying to access:

```
var qName:QName = new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","score1");
trace(myXML.descendants(qName)[0].toString()); // 105
```

Comment: Hello I did try this before I believe, but just to make sure I ran it through again and got this error:                           TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at parser_fla::MainTimeline/xmlLoaded()[parser_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:14]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: @Scientific - That could be caused by attempting to reference a score that doesn't exist. Eg, `score6`.

Comment: Hello, myXML..score1[0].toString() looks correct, why would this be trying to reference a score that does not exist? The tag <score1> is in my xml file above, it just keeps throwing that error?

Comment: @Scientific - Okay, updated my answer.  I've never run into a situation where I had to use fully qualified names for elements, but I'm guessing this is one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!  I appreciate all of your help merv.

Answer (score 2):

You get undefined because you don't have "scores1" tag in your xml.
Try this:

```
trace(myXML.scores.id.toString());
trace(myXML.scores.score1.toString());
trace(myXML.scores.score2.toString());
trace(myXML.scores.score3.toString());
trace(myXML.scores.score4.toString());
trace(myXML.scores.score5.toString());
```

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for your answer, I see that I did make a mistake.  However, the scores do not output as text in the output box using your method.  Something still must be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather more indepth post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143291/parsing-xml-in-a-flash-file/8148042#8148042), but you would essentially grab all score tags, then sum them.  You must also take into account the xmlns defined on the feed node.

The following code would work for score1 to scoreX:

```
var namespace:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

var score:XML;
var scores:XMLList = xml..namespace::scores.*.(/^http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/Atom::score/.test(name()));

if(!scores)
{
    return;
}

var final:Number = 0;
for each(score in scores)
{
    final += Number(score.text());
}

trace(final); // 299
```

You could probably simplify the regex by referencing the namespace variable.

Best of luck!

**[[Edit]]**

Modified to reference the namespace:

```
var regex:RegExp = new RegExp(namespace.toString().replace(/\//g, "\\/") + "::score");
var scores:XMLList = xml..namespace::scores.*.(regex.test(name()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import gs.dataTransfer.XMLParser;

XMLParser.load("myDocument.xml", onFinish);

function onFinish($success:Boolean, $results:Object, $xml:XML):Void



{ //This function gets called when the XML gets parsed.

    if ($success) {

        trace("The first book is: "+$results.Book[0].name);
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Its better na....like this

use scores,id,score1 xml tag in split places

```
var xml=Xml as String;
trace(xml);
var xmlfull=xml.split("scores").length - 1;
trace(xmlfull);
for (var i = 1; i <= xmlfull; i++) 
{
  trace(xml.split("id")[i].split("id")[0]);
  trace(xml.split("score1")[i].split("score1")[0]);
  trace(xml.split("score2")[i].split("score2")[0]);
}
```